# CSV export hidden series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, export-to-csv

I have a chart with 2 series, one of which I should not be visible. However, that data should be present in the CSV export. Setting,

```
showInLegend: false,
visible: false
```

hides that series in the chart, however it also does not export in the CSV. How can I disable a series to be displayed, but enable its export?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/absessive/cqjvD/1109/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[THe plugin](http://highcharts.github.io/export-csv/export-csv.js) that you are using is checking if series is visible - if you remove that check, then hidden series will be included in exported CSV.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cqjvD/1111/

Changed line in the plugin:

```
      if (series.options.includeInCSVExport !== false) { // #55
```